# Next.js (TypeError: dispatch is not a function)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

I am using a global context for authentication in my Next.js app the same way I used to implement in React.js. However, I am getting **TypeError: dispatch is not a function** when calling dispatch!

I tried to solve it but did not manage to get it done.

Here is my code:

**AuthContext.jsx**

```
import { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";
import { authReducer } from "./AuthReducer";

export const AuthContext = createContext({});

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const initialAuthContext = {
    isGuest: true,
    loginAction: {
      inProgress: false,
      succeeded: false,
      finished: false,
      result: null,
      error: null,
    },
    logoutAction: {
      inProgress: false,
      succeeded: false,
      finished: false,
      result: null,
      error: null,
    },
    userInfo: {},
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, initialAuthContext);
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export function useAuthContext() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export default AuthProvider;
```

AuthReducer.jsx

```
export const authReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isGeust: false,
        loginAction: {
          ...state.loginAction,
          inProgress: false,
          succeeded: true,
          finished: true,
          error: "",
        },
        userInfo: action.payload.user,
        token: action.payload.token,
      };

    case "USER_LOGIN_FAIL":
      return {
        ...state,
        isGeust: true,
        loginAction: {
          ...state.loginAction,
          inProgress: false,
          succeeded: false,
          finished: true,
          error: action.payload.error, 
        },
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

in the login page, I am trying to dispatch an action as follows:

```
import { useAuthContext } from "@/src/context/auth/AuthContext";

  const { dispatch } = useAuthContext();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (success) {
      dispatch({ type: "USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: response });
    }
    if (error) dispatch({ type: "USER_LOGIN_FAIL", payload: response });
  }, [success, error]);
```

Tried several methods

Answer (score 0):

The reason is its returning **dispatch** function undefined because you didn't wrap AuthProvider inside root level of your application.

In next js you can add AuthProvider inside _app.js file like this -

```js
<AuthProvider>
     <Component {...pageProps} />
 </AuthProvider>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I already wrapped the root level with the AuthProvider, so the problem is present even with the root component wrapped.

Comment: Share it how you have wrapped. I tested code its working fine just after wrapping.